# Add Customer Fields to Jmeter HTML and CSV Report

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I want to add extra fields to my *Jmeter HTM*L and CSV.
As below.

1 When i run my *Jmeter Test Suite* , i pass a paramter to the same which is the configuration on which my application is running. I store the paramter somewhere in Jmeter.

bat  `"C:\MSG-Team\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin\jmeter.bat -n -t C:\MSG-Team\Jenkins\Test_Set_Files\TestSet1.jmx -Congif=XYZ-l C:\MSG-Team\Jenkins\Post_Processing_CSV\TestSet1_ConfigXYZ_Seperate_Service_Mode.csv -e -o C:\MSG-Team\Jenkins\Results_Directory\HTMLReport"`

2 Once the execution is done i have the CSV report generated with a extra column that will hold the value for config that i had earlier sent as input parameter while executing the test.

3 Now i execute different test set with different configs.

4 Now i merge all the CSV

5 Now i generate the HTML report where inside the Statistics part i want the column Config name to be included.

Any thoughts / guidance on how to achieve this.

I have already checked the reportgenerator.properties and user.properties for the same but still not luck.
Any help for the same is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm hoping I'm understanding correctly what you are attempting to do...

I would add a BeanShell PostProcessor to a sample and make sure that you can actually see the variable i.e.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService;

try {
String config= vars.get("yourconfigname");

}
catch (Throwable ex) {
    log.error("Error in Beanshell", ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

If you can see it then all you have to do is to add that variable to user.properties

i.e.

```
sample_variables=yourconfigname
```

You would then have to edit the XSL that is used to generate the report to query then render the "yourconfigname" variable..

Comment: By adding sample_variables=ConfigurationName in the user.properties file i am able to add the extra the column to the report , and that solves 33% of my problem

1 ) How to do i set the value of the same now ? I want to be able to pass the value via CLI when i invoke the test set.
(Same value across all the rows)

2 ) Also where do i find the XSL that is used to generate the HTML report so that i can modify it accordingly.

Comment: In order to set the value you must ensure that you are getting it in on your test samples from the suite invocation ? Use the BeanShell approach as shown above on a sample.. If you need to then set it to the variable name mentioned in user.properties you simply do a vars.put("yourconfigname",yourconfigvalue)); The XSL files usually reside in the "extras" folder under you JMeter Installation..

Comment: Added the same but it results in error 2019-08-19 15:43:53,713 WARN o.a.j.e.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval In file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService;  try { vars.put("Configur . . . '' Encountered ")" at line 4, column 40.